# Disable submit btn

Tags: javascript, razor

this maybe a simple question but not for me. I have a form that has a phone number field in i have JS to restrict users to a certain format. The problem is when they input less then 10 digits it still allows them to submit.
Here is my js:

```
 $('#phone-number')

            .keydown(function (e) {
                var key = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
                $phone = $(this);

                // Don't let them remove the starting '('
                if ($phone.val().length === 1 && (key === 8 || key === 46)) {
                    $phone.val('(');
                    return false;
                }
                // Reset if they highlight and type over first char.
                else if ($phone.val().charAt(0) !== '(') {
                    $phone.val('(' + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + '');
                }

                // Auto-format- do not expose the mask as the user begins to type
                if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
                    if ($phone.val().length === 4) {
                        $phone.val($phone.val() + ')');
                    }
                    if ($phone.val().length === 5) {
                        $phone.val($phone.val() + ' ');
                    }
                    if ($phone.val().length === 9) {
                        $phone.val($phone.val() + '-');
                    }
                }

                // Allow numeric (and tab, backspace, delete) keys only
                return (key == 8 ||
                    key == 9 ||
                    key == 46 ||
                    (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                    (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
            })

            .bind('focus click', function () {
                $phone = $(this);

                if ($phone.val().length === 0) {
                    $phone.val('(');
                }
                else {
                    var val = $phone.val();
                    $phone.val('').val(val); // Ensure cursor remains at the end
                }
            })

            .blur(function () {
                $phone = $(this);

                if ($phone.val() === '(') {
                    $phone.val('');
                }
            });
```

This is the phone number box:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.phoneNumber)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.phoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", minlength = "5", oncopy = "return false", onpaste = "return false",
       id = "phone-number" ,name = "phone-number", type = "text", maxlength = "14" , placeholder = "(XXX) XXX-XXXX"
   })
    </div>
```

This is the Submit btn

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Results" id="Submit" disabled="disabled" >Submit</button`>

I don't know if you need this information but this Enable the submit btn after the boxes are filled in JS

```
 $("input[type=text]").keyup(function () {

            if
            (
                $("#firstName").val().trim().length !== 0 &&
                $("#lastName").val().trim().length !== 0 &&
              //  $("#phoneNumber").val().trim().length !== 0 &&
                $("#address").val().trim().length !== 0
            ) {

                $("#Submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#Submit").addClass("btn--primary");
            } else {
                $("#Submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
```

Thank you and sorry if it is an easy question but I tried in many places.

Comment: Where is the code which checks phoneNumber length and disable/enable the button? The code you have posted has that commented out and also that commented out code enables the button whenever phone number length is not 0.

Comment: @kanhaishah that is the issue I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the help but for me this works the best and easiest. 
//This script will prevent the user from Submitting if the Phone number box is less than

```
function validatePhone() {
        var phoneNumberPattern = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
        var phoneNumber = $("#phone-number").val();
        if (phoneNumberPattern.test(phoneNumber)) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;


    }
    //Here we make sure that all boxes are filled then Submit.
    $("input[type=text]").keyup(function () {

        if
        (

            validatePhone()
        ) {

            $("#Submit").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#Submit").addClass("btn--primary");
        } else {
            $("#Submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
```

//this is the submit btn

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Results" id="Submit" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is stop the form submission from going through. You can do this by attaching an on submit event to the form and `preventDefault` within it. For example:

```
$('#FORM_ID').submit(function (e) {
    if ($('#phone-number').val().replace(/[^\d]/g,'').length < 10){ // check if phone number is less than 10 digits
        // phone number is less than 10 digits, prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault()
        return false
    }
})
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Here's how my validation of the phone number input (`$('#phone-number').val().replace(/[^\d]/g,'').length < 10`) works:

1. I get the value of the phone number input: `$('#phone-number').val()`
2. I remove any characters that are not numbers `replace(/[^\d]/g,'')`
3. Then I get the length of the resulting numbers. If it's less than 10, I prevent the form from submitting via `e.preventDefault()`

Note: you will have to replace `#FORM_ID` with the id of the form you want to run this validation for.

Comment: I don't know how to add the validation. Sorry, it didn't work

Comment: @CountLessQ I have updated my answer to hopefully get it working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an input with [`type="tel"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel) and the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel#pattern) attribute? It doesn't disable the submit button like you asked, but it can validate the user input against a certain pattern.

Below a few examples of inputs using a pattern. The first accepts exactly 10 digits, the second accepts 10 digits or more, the third accepts a strict format similar to your inputs placeholder:

```html
<form>
  <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}" placeholder="Exactly 10 digits"><br>
  <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10,}" placeholder="10 digits or more"><br>
  <input type="tel" pattern="\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" maxlength="14" placeholder="(123) 456-7890"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```